# Wordpress text widget spinner never-ending spinning

Tags: wordpress, widget, text-widget

I'm trying to update my HTML code in the Enhanced Text widget within my first footer widget section. When I go to save the updated HTML code, the "saving spinner" will never finish rotating and the changes will not save. I'm just adding image HTML code. I've tried creating Text widget within any of the other footer widget sections, however the same result happened there as well. This issue is very strange since I've done the changes successfully on my staging website which is almost identical in makeup. I have both my staging website and my live website at the latest version of Wordpress.

Do anyone know any tips for fixing this?

Comment: This sounds as if there may be a permissions issue with writing the file, but to be honest there isn't enough information here to troubleshoot effectively. Open up your browser's console before you press save, then press save and see if you get any console errors or network errors and post them within your question if you do.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thank you for responding. I tried to save the changes today and it seems that the changes went through fine for some reason. I really didn't do anything to my website after commenting. Before I tried to make changes to my text widget, I updated my Wordpress install to the latest version. That could possibly be the reason... I'll reply to the ticket if it starts happening again.